# In which format I should send http POST to Bot Builder?

Tags: rest, botframework

I was trying to built a bot which interacts with multiple users.
The Microsoft Bot Builder seems nice to me.
I followed their examples and tried them out. 
[Bot Builder Restify and so on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-quickstart#install-the-sdk)

There are few things which are not clear to me.

1. How can I post a message to bot rest endpoint?
   The emulator seems to have been taking care of such details. But in a real application, in which format i should sent a message?
2. How does the bot interacts with multiple users? In the emulator, there is only one user, what happens if there are several persons talk to the bot at the same time in a real application?
   I think "chatconnector" somehow doing the job, but I am not sure.

I hope someone could point out examples or give answers below to clarify these to me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: At least intercepting the message and taking look at http request can give some idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Messages are sent using industry-standard REST and JSON over HTTPS.  Although you can call the bot's endpoint directly, this would bypass channels and security.  In the Microsoft Bot Framework architecture, clients communicate with a channel connector and the channel connector calls the bot.  When the bot responds, it sends a message to the channel connector and the connector calls the client.  The channel connectors transform messages from the channel's specific schema to the Bot Framework's generic activity schema and back.  They also verify that callers are authorized using JWT tokens.

This documentation on Authentication might help clear things up some: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-authentication

2) Group conversations are handled differently, depending on the channel.  This sample demonstrates some of the group conversation features in the Bot Builder Node sdk: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/core-GetConversationMembers